# Imprimir a un fichero

Tags: c#, visual-studio, archivo, visual-studio-2017, impresora

Buenas a todos.

Resulta que llevo un tiempo pegándome intentando hacer lo que dice en el título y se me están acabando las ideas.

Hace unos meses desarrollé un módulo de impresión con la clase *PrintDocument* que dibuja las líneas de texto e imágenes que me interesan usando el evento de impresión combinado con la clase *Graphics* de *PrintPageEventArgs*.
Ahora me gustaría adaptar esto a, en vez de imprimir a una impresora, hacerlo a un fichero, una imágen.

He pensado si habría alguna manera de extraer el documento que se genera cuando llamas a *PrintPreviewDialog*, o directamente tal como hace *PrintPageEventArgs*, en vez de mandar las líneas a la impresora, las mande a un fichero. Si hay más formas me gustaría conocerlas también.

Muchas gracias a todos, un saludo.

Comment: Creo que con PrintDocument no es posible. Tal vez lo que puedas hacer es dibujar en un bitmap y despues guardarlo como imagen.

Comment: Puede ser, pero aun así, si yo uso la clase que me da un Control para previsualizar la impresión, PrintPreviewDialog, puedo ver en vivo lo que se ha generado antes de la impresión. ¿No hay manera de extraer ese documento?

Comment: Si,puede ser. Pero lo que te va a dar no es una imagen, sino un documento xps creo. Intenta con `PrinterSettings.PrintToFile`, pero como te digo, no te va a dar una imagen sino un archivo en un formato propio de microsoft xps